# Animation: light is shining through plane: how to stop that

Tags: animation, light

Using Blender 2.77a. I've made a lighthouse scene with a rotating spot lamp. When the lamp moves by the hill in the background, the lamp shines through the hill. The hill is a plane.
How can I stop the light from shining through the hill?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Is the cone just a texture? Then it'd be pretty hard. if you used a spot light and volumetrics (e.g. fog with light shining through) you'd get better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a spot with **Halo** enabled.

Change the **Spot Shape > Step** value to 1.

This will block the Halo.

See the image below.

[image]